# Building dymanic query with many laterail joins

Tags: sql, postgresql, entity-attribute-value

I am building a dynamic query based on user-submitted conditions on user-specified fields.

I have a two tables

```
Visitors(id, name, email...)
```

and a

```
Trackings(id, visitor_id, field, string_value, integer_value, boolean_value, date_value)
```

The conditions comes in the form of an array of SQL fragments built earlier. Default filters for attributes that are hardcoded on the `visitors table`, and custom filters, for the values that are user-submitted and stored in an EAV schema (trackings)

Example:

```
Default:
{"name ILIKE 'Jack'", "(last_seen < (current_date - (7 || ' days')::interval))"}

Custom:
{"field = 'number_of_orders' > 10", "is_pro_user = true"}
```

A visitor can have many trackings, each one recording some custom, user-submitted data field for that visitor. But each visitor also has some default data that lies on the table itself, such as `email`, `name` or `last_seen` etc.

Now, users should be to ask queries such as:

- Give me all the visitors for which no custom field named `number_of_orders` has been recored (is unknown)
- Give me all visitors with the default attribute `name` set to `Jack` and for who the custom attribute `total_purchase_value` is greater than `1000`

My attempt at solving it was using a stored procedure that dynamically concatenated a series of conditions using AND (for default data on the visitor table), and OR statements (for the custom data in the trackings table) inside a WHERE-caluse

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION find_matching_visitors(app_id text, default_filters text[], custom_filters text[])
RETURNS TABLE (
  id varchar
) AS
$body$
DECLARE
    default_filterstring text;
    custom_filterstring text;
    default_filter_length integer;
    custom_filter_length integer;
    sql VARCHAR;
BEGIN
    default_filter_length := COALESCE(array_length(default_filters, 1), 0);
    custom_filter_length := COALESCE(array_length(custom_filters, 1), 0);

    default_filterstring := array_to_string(default_filters, ' AND ');
    custom_filterstring := array_to_string(custom_filters, ' OR ');

    IF custom_filterstring = '' or custom_filterstring is null THEN
        custom_filterstring := '1=1';
    END IF;

    IF default_filterstring = '' or default_filterstring is null THEN
        default_filterstring := '1=1';
    END IF;

    sql := format('
                SELECT v.id FROM visitors v
                LEFT JOIN trackings t on v.id = t.visitor_id
                WHERE v.app_id = app_id and (%s) and (%s)
                group by v.id
                having case when %s > 0 then count(v.id) = %s else true end
            ', custom_filterstring, default_filterstring, custom_filter_length, custom_filter_length);
    RETURN QUERY EXECUTE sql;

END;
$body$
LANGUAGE 'plpgsql';
```

This works great, but AFAIK there is not way to express the `unknown` filter for a custom attribute. In that it would require using a `left outer join`, or a `not exists` subquery with access to the outer scope.

I am now looking at alternative ways to accomplish the same as above, but also support this kind of query. I am thinking something like the below, using a series of lateral joins for each condition, but this seems like it won't perform very well as soon as there is more than 1-2 conditions/joins.

```
select v.id, v.name from visitors v
inner join lateral ( <-- custom fields
    select * from trackings t
    where field = 'admin'
) as t1 on t1.visitor_id = v.id
inner join lateral (
    select * from trackings t
    where field = 'users_created' 
) as t2 on t2.visitor_id = v.id
inner join lateral (
    select * from trackings t
    where field = 'teams_created' and integer_value > 0
) as t3 on t3.visitor_id = v.id
where v.app_id = 'ASnYW1-RgCl0I' and (v.type = 'lead' or v.type = 'user')
and name ILIKE 'mads' and email is not null // <-- default fields
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: I don't see any need for a lateral join here. You are not using columns from the outer tables in the derived tables. A good old (left) join will do just fine.

Comment: I see, but still I'll be performing lots of joins on the same table

Comment: Welcome to the perils of the "EAV" anti-pattern

Comment: Yes, but I still managed to express almost everything I wanted using the first option.

It's just because in addition to filters like `greater_than`, `is`, `contains`, I also need the `value_unknown` filter, and I hoped that would be a solution close to what I had original come up with.